# Setting up integer texture and binding as image

Tags: opengl, texture

**When I set up a texture as float it works (color is written -  BTW I'm doing voxelization):**

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, depth, 0, GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,NULL);
```

then setting filtering...

then binding:

```
glBindImageTexture(0, textureID, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
```

writing:

```
layout(rgba32f ,binding = 0) uniform image3D geometryGrid;
...
imageStore(geometryGrid, index, ivec4(1.0)); //ivec4 or vec4, it works
```

reading:

```
uniform sampler3D geometryTexture;
...
vec4 g = texture(geometryTexture, geomCoords);
```

**But I want to use an integer texture (so in future I can do binary voxelization and bitwise operations - each bit = slice in z direction). I set it up like that:**

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, depth, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_INT, NULL);
```

then setting filtering...

then binding:

```
glBindImageTexture(0, textureID, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32I);
```

writing:

```
layout(rgba32i ,binding = 0) uniform iimage3D geometryGrid;
...
imageStore(geometryGrid, index, ivec4(1.0));
```

reading (same as float):

```
uniform sampler3D geometryTexture;
...
vec4 g = texture(geometryTexture, geomCoords);
```

Then it's black. Whats wrong with that? There is sparse documentation about it. BTW The info that `iimage` is for integer texture, `uimage` is for unsigned int is actually nowhere to be found.

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return any errors during the process?

Comment: No, it returns 0 after each step.

Comment: For future readers this issue was continued at: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/setting-up-integer-texture-and-binding-as-image-pt-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, depth, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_INT, NULL);
> ```

This is not an [integer image format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats). It's an unsigned, normalized, fixed-point image format. For those, you use floating-point image/sampler variables. So for a 3D texture, you would use `image3D`, not `iimage3D`.

If you want a *true* signed integer format, you would do this:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA32I, width, height, depth, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_INT, NULL);
```

Note two changes. First, the internal format is `GL_RGBA32I`, which specifies a 32-bit-per-channel signed integer format. The second is the use of `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` for the [pixel transfer format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format). Even though you're not actually performing a pixel transfer (since you're passing NULL), you still must use an appropriate format and type. And the `_INTEGER` formats must be used if you're transferring to/from a texture with an integer format.

When you do this, you must of course use the `iimage3D` and `isampler3D` types in your shaders.

Comment: Thanks for hints. I corrected glTexImage3D function as you pointed but the problem seem to persist. What I noticed is that when I setup texture as RGBA32F, RGBA, GL_FLOAT and then bind it as RGBA32I image and use iimage in shader it works. But if I setup texture as RGBA32I, RGBA_INTEGER, GL_INT is is empty. So it is something with texture setup still. But it *is* correct and glGetError returns 0... I updated my nvidia drivers but this is not driver fault.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sampler3D, you should use isampler3D to sample integer formats as described in the [GLSL documentation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)).